# Unexpected output when sorting array of objects, javascript inline conditionals

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I am attempting to get sorted indices of an array of objects, based on a property value. I have the following simplified example:

```js
let myObj = {myArray:[{amt:0.02380952380952380},{amt:1.0238095238095237},{amt:0.02380952380952380},{amt:-0.02380952380952380}]}
let indices = new Array;

for (let i = 0; i < myObj.myArray.length; i++) {
  indices[i] = i
}

let items = myObj.myArray.slice();
indices.sort((a, b) => (items[a].amt > items[b].amt)
                        ? 1
                        : ((items[b].amt > items[a].amt) ? -1 : 0));

console.log(indices) //gives [ 3, 0, 2, 1 ] expected [ 2, 3, 1, 0 ] or [ 1, 3, 2, 0 ]
```

The resulting `indices` array doesn't produce the ordering I'm expecting.

Is there something simple/obvious I'm missing here?

Note I'm unsure between [ 2, 3, 1, 0 ] or [ 1, 3, 2, 0 ] as different browsers may interpret the equal values differently, from https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort

> If compareFunction(a, b) returns 0, leave a and b unchanged with
>   respect to each other, but sorted with respect to all different
>   elements. Note: the ECMAscript standard does not guarantee this
>   behavior, thus, not all browsers (e.g. Mozilla versions dating back to
>   at least 2003) respect this.

Comment: Care to explain why you would expect _two_ different results (_"expected [ 2, 3, 1, 0 ] or [ 1, 3, 2, 0 ]"_) when sorting the array?

Comment: @Andreas there are two identical values in the `myArray` objects. I'm unsure what the expected order of those would be in the output...

Comment: @Andreas I've added a little more info on this, thanks

Comment: `myObj[3].amt` is the smallest, `myObj[1].amt` is the largest. The order `3, 0, 2, 1` seems perfectly OK to me. Why are you expecting 3 to be somewhere in the middle?

Comment: @mbojko you're right.. I had got a little confused earlier - and was aiming for the position of the lowest in `myArray` followed by position of 2nd etc. Perhaps should have said "desired" rather than "expected". I did resolve in the answer, but there may be a better way...

Answer (score -1):

The above code is behaving properly. I used `indexOf` to get the desired output:

```
let indices2 = new Array;
for (let i= 0; i<myObj.myArray.length;i++){ indices2[i] = indices.indexOf(i) }
```

Full example:

```html
<html>
<head>
<script>
let myObj = {myArray:[{amt:0.02380952380952380},{amt:1.0238095238095237},{amt:0.023809523809523},{amt:-0.02380952380952380}]}
let indices = new Array;
let indices2 = new Array;

for (let i= 0; i<myObj.myArray.length;i++){ indices[i] = i }
let items = myObj.myArray.slice();
indices.sort((a,b)=> (items[a].amt > items[b].amt) ? 1 : ((items[b].amt > items[a].amt) ? -1 : 0));
for (let i= 0; i<myObj.myArray.length;i++){ indices2[i] = indices.indexOf(i) }
console.log(indices,indices2)  // indices gives [ 3, 0, 2, 1 ] indices2 gives [ 2, 3, 1, 0 ] 

</script>
</head>
</html>
```